# Load balancing a website using different domains

Tags: php, html, load, load-balancing

We have a simple PHP site. It is getting hit quite a bit. We have 2 main parts. One is a drop down menu that is updated using AJAX when the user changes the text in the search box.

Next, we have a set of results. We are trying to make it an "instant" search, so it updates as the user changes what is in the box. We are worried about load issues. We want to split up the main page from the suggestions and results pages. We hoped to distribute the lag on different servers. When AJAXing this content, they will have different URLs and browsers do not allow this.

Is there a way to alleviate this problem? Or is there a more efficient way to distribute the load?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) to perform AJAX like stuff to a different domain.